# How to write in arabic using lstlinsting for the JSON and XML environment?

Tags: arabic, xml, json

I'm an IT developer, and for some reason I've JSON and XML to make in report but with Arabic.

For JSON and XML environment I'm using this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}

\lstdefinelanguage{json}{
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\scriptsize,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=lines,
    backgroundcolor=\color{background},
    literate=
     *{0}{{{\color{numb}0}}}{1}
      {1}{{{\color{numb}1}}}{1}
      {2}{{{\color{numb}2}}}{1}
      {3}{{{\color{numb}3}}}{1}
      {4}{{{\color{numb}4}}}{1}
      {5}{{{\color{numb}5}}}{1}
      {6}{{{\color{numb}6}}}{1}
      {7}{{{\color{numb}7}}}{1}
      {8}{{{\color{numb}8}}}{1}
      {9}{{{\color{numb}9}}}{1}
      {:}{{{\color{punct}{:}}}}{1}
      {,}{{{\color{punct}{,}}}}{1}
      {\{}{{{\color{delim}{\{}}}}{1}
      {\}}{{{\color{delim}{\}}}}}{1}
      {[}{{{\color{delim}{[}}}}{1}
      {]}{{{\color{delim}{]}}}}{1},
}
```

and make text like that:

```
\begin{document} 
\chapter*{Preambule}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=json,firstnumber=1]

    <reversegeocode timestamp="Sun, 19 Jan 20 11:23:54 +0000" attribution="Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" querystring="format=xml&lat=36.77618515&lon=3.05828603472308&zoom=18&addressdetails=1">
        <result place_id="169689605" osm_type="way" osm_id="355559012" ref="Place Emir Abdelkader" lat="36.77618515" lon="3.05828603472308" boundingbox="36.7760136,36.7763549,3.0581641,3.0584054">
        Place Emir Abdelkader, ساحة الامير عبد القادر, Alger Centre, Daïra Sidi M'Hamed, Alger, Algérie
        </result>
        <addressparts>
        <address29>Place Emir Abdelkader</address29>
        <road>ساحة الامير عبد القادر</road>
        <town>Alger Centre</town>
        <county>Daïra Sidi M'Hamed</county>
        <state>Alger</state>
        <country>Algérie</country>
        <country_code>dz</country_code>
        </addressparts>
        </reversegeocode>
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

My problem is that the Arabic text will be shown as `????????` How to fix that?

Comment: I don't think that it will work without marking the Arabic in the xml to escape to latex.

Comment: It's preferable to post a complete compilable example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi, 
@UlrikeFischer , can be clearer please.

Comment: @SalimBou , I have correct and post a complete compilable exemple ... thanks for helping

Comment: Your example  still not compilable, If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you.